# Finding the transfer function of this RC circuit

Tags: parallel, transfer-function

I have the following circuit and I need to find the transfer function:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjui0Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Considering the position of \$V_{\text{out}}\$, it looks like I can combine the \$R\$ and \$C\$ in parallel both above and below \$V_{\text{out}}\$ and then use voltage division to get the voltage across the bottom \$R\$ and \$C\$ in parallel: 
$$V_{\text{out}} = V_{\text{in}}\frac{R||C}{(R||C)+(R||C)}$$
And this would leave me with a transfer function of:
$$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}}=\frac{1}{2}$$
However, I'm pretty sure this isn't correct.  Am I looking at the circuit incorrectly when assuming I can combine the \$R\$ and \$C\$ in parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the \$R\$ and \$C\$ to be in parallel, you would need \$V_{\text{out}} = 0\$ due to a short circuit. But that's not the case.

First calculate \$V_{\text{out+}}\$, the voltage at the + terminal of \$V_{\text{out}}\$. This is just a voltage divider:

$$V_{\text{out+}} = \frac{1/sC}{1/sC + R}V_{\text{in}} = \frac{1}{1 + sRC}V_{\text{in}}$$

Now calculate \$V_{\text{out-}}\$, the voltage at the - terminal of \$V_{\text{out}}\$. This is also just a voltage divider:

$$V_{\text{out-}} = \frac{R}{1/sC + R}V_{\text{in}} = \frac{sRC}{1 + sRC}V_{\text{in}}$$

Now you can calculate \$V_{\text{out}}\$:

$$V_{\text{out}} = V_{\text{out+}} - V_{\text{out-}}$$

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're not treating the capacitance correctly as a frequency-dependent impedance.  Your equation is only valid at a single frequency.

The way to do this is to write the transfer function for the low-pass section (Vout+), then write down the transfer function for the high-pass section (Vout-) then take the difference (vout = vout+ - vout-).

Comment: Your method is correct, but the issue is not what you've stated. Assuming the Vout/Vin relationship is as given in the question, the frequency dependence cancels when simplified. The issue is that the resistor and capacitor are not in parallel, so the Vout/Vin relationship given in the question is not correct.

Comment: If Ryan (the OP) had calculated each TF independently it would have been obvious they weren't in parallel, so I still think the core issue was Ryan didn't understand what a differential output was.  I suspect he just wanted you to do the math for him and I'm sure he is glad you were so accommodating.