# Voltage divider (phasor domain)

Tags: voltage-divider

In the circuit below, I have to calculate \$V_u\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUyj8F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

By applying the voltage divider between the series resistances below, I get $$V_u=V_e\frac{R}{R+R}-V_e\frac{R}{R+R}=0$$
However if I apply the voltage divider to the two elements above, I get $$V_u=V_e\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}-V_e\frac{\frac{1}{j\omega C}}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}$$

The solution gives directly:

$$V_u=V_e\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{j\omega C}}-V_e\frac{R}{R+R}$$

Why? How did it apply the formula?

Comment: This is basically the same question as [this one](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164603/finding-the-transfer-function-of-this-rc-circuit), except that this has an extra resistor instead of a capacitor. [My answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/164608/51760) explains the process for finding the differential voltage (\$V_u\$ in your case).

Answer (score 1):

The potential difference \$V_u\$ is the difference between the voltage drops across the two resistors in the two legs. Hench they have applied 2 voltage dividers to find the potentials across each of the resistors.

$$V_{R2}=V_e\times\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{jwC}} = \text{potential across the resistor in the second leg} $$

$$V_{R1} = V_e \times \frac{R}{R+R}=\text{Potential across the resistor in the first leg}$$

\$V_u\$ is simply the difference between the potentials above.

---

In the method you have used you are mistaking what \$V_u\$ stands for and thats where you are going wrong.

Comment: Check your formula, it is wrong (a voltage is missing).